# Importar CSV en MySQL con un script bash

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, csv, shell-script

Ya no se en que estoy fallando.

La idea es simple, es un CSV, delimitado y con cabecera. La tabla ya existe en el MySQL y el usuario es el propietario de objetos. ¿Qué falla en la línea del `mysqlimport`??? el parámetro lo coge bien, el fichero lo localiza correctamente...

¿Por qué cambia las comillas en la salida para el `'--fields-terminated-by=;'`?

Y el mensaje que devuelve es :

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+ echo 'LOGIN CORRECTO'
LOGIN CORRECTO
+ echo 'Importando fichero...'
Importando fichero...
+ mysqlimport '--fields-terminated-by=;' '--lines-terminated-by=\n' -u user -pPass BBDD /path/inputs/app/pro/filename_20230726.txt
mysqlimport: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

```
#!/bin/bash

# show commands being executed, per debug
set -x

# define database connectivity
_db_server="Servidor"
_db_port="Puerto"
_db="BBDD"
_db_user="User"
_db_password="Pass"
_table_name="Tabla"
_db_date=$1

# define directory containing CSV files
_csv_directory="/path/inputs/app/pro"

# go into directory
cd $_csv_directory

# get a list of CSV files in directory
_files=`ls -1 bal*$_db_date.txt`

echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

  mysql -u $_db_user -p$_db_password -h $_db_server -P $_db_port -D $_db << OK1
OK1
echo "LOGIN CORRECTO"
echo "Importando fichero..."
  # import csv into mysql
  mysqlimport --fields-terminated-by=";" --lines-terminated-by="\n" -u $_db_user -p$_db_password $_db $_csv_directory/$_files >> OK2

echo "FALLO AL IMPORTAR"
exit
OK2
echo "Importado correcto"
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"


#done
exit
```